# Do the monster's abilities cool down faster while in combat?

Tags: evolve-big-alpha

I was warned not to shoot the monster while it was escaping with the explanation that the Goliath would be able to leap more, while they're in combat. I've heard similarly about the Kraken, that they would be able to fly as long as they were taking damage, but I never noticed the same with the Goliath. Is it true?

I'd also like to ask follow-up questions, like what "in combat" means and which abilities are affected.

Comment: I do not know anything about the game, but "in combat" usually, in MOBA enviorement and such, means while you attack or you are getting attacked.
For example: you gain 10% movement speed after 2 seconds you're out of combat.